# When looping through all processes, the process name stays the same but the process ID changes

Tags: c++, process

So I want to get the list of all processes running on the system (Windows) and print out the process ID with the name in this format:

```
Process ID - Process Name
```

The code works and it prints out the process ID and process name but the process name stays the same all the time even though the process ID beside the name is changing, for instance (example output):

```
Process ID - Process Name
13044           007FF61C
13220           007FF61C
11752           007FF61C
```

My code which gets the processes and prints the ID and name looks like this:

```
void misc::get_processes(void) {

    HANDLE process_snapshot;
    PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;

    process_snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);

    if (process_snapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        cout << "CreateToolhelp32Snapshot() returned INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE" << endl;

    pe32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

    if (!Process32First(process_snapshot, &pe32))
        cout << "Process32First() returned an error" << endl;

    cout << "Process ID - Process Name" << endl;

    do 
        cout << pe32.th32ProcessID << "\t\t" << pe32.szExeFile << endl;
    while (Process32Next(process_snapshot, &pe32));
}
```

Also I wanted to include that the process name changes when I restart the program, for instance from:

```
006FF74C
```

to:

```
0019FA6C
```

Comment: try using wcout instead of cout.

Comment: Not quite. You never closed your snapshot handle That will eventually come back to bite you. Make sure yo you close it before leaving this function.

Comment: @WhozCraig thanks I will definitely add it later

Comment: If `wcout` works, it means you are compiling for Unicode, where `Process32(First|Next)` maps to `Process32(First|Next)W`, and `PROCESSENTRY32` maps to `PROCESSENTRY32W`, thus `pe32.szExeFile` is a `wchar_t[]` array. The fact that `cout` was printing out memory addresses should have warned you that `pe32.szExeFile` wasn't a `char[]` array. `cout` does not support `wchar_t` data